# не работает UCWA и Skype Web SDK

Tags: javascript, https, skype, skype-web-sdk

Как пройти авторизацию Skype через Web SDK (UCWA) на основе официальных примеров ?

У меня есть купленный аккаунт для использования Skype for Business плюс вход в админ панель Office 365. Были скачаны официальные примеры  [Skype Web SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn986863(v=office.16).aspx) и [UCWA](https://ucwa.skype.com/code) , которые развернуты на локальной машине (Apache сервер с директорией localhost). 
Для входа я использовал учетную запись пользователь@домен (art@shockw4ves.onmicrosoft.com) которую я создал при покупке Skype for Business. В итоге я получаю ответ в виде всплывающего сообщения `Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin`

[image: авторизация в ucwa]

В заголовке запроса к `https://lyncdiscover.shockw4ves.onmicrosoft.com/xframe` есть атрибут `X-Ms-Origin:http://localhost`, может в этом проблема? Достаточно долгий процесс отладки привел меня к мысли подключить фрейм вручную и общатся с ним через post message, это возможно?

Comment: подскажите, уже месяц как мучает вопрос

Comment: помогите оч нужно